# How to combine timelimit and gap termination criterion in CPLEX using JAVA concert

Tags: java, time, limit, cplex, termination

I'm solving very large instances for a MIP and would like to combine the two termination criterions. I know how to use the timeLimit and the relative MIP gap both individually and at the same time i.e.

```
cplex.setParam(IloCplex.Param.MIP.Tolerances.MIPGap, 0.1);
cplex.setParam(IloCplex.Param.TimeLimit, 3600);
```

For several instances I would like to combine the two criterions two have the following two phases:

- Phase 1: Runtime up to 1h (no gap limit => solve to optimality)
- if no optimal solution was found in first 1h :
- Phase 2: Runtime up to 5h (maximum of 4 additional hours) & gap limit = 0.1 i.e. whatever limit is reached first terminates the search

I can think of two approaches on how to achieve that:

- Set certain parameters in the model to run it in the proposed two stage approach
- Start the optimization with default values (i.e. no time or gap limit), monitor the runtime, if it is still running after 1h => add time and gap limit as termination criterion.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to implement these approaches.

Suggestions, other ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the [advanced start switch](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/AdvInd.html) parameter is set to 1.  So, for phase 1, you can simply run the model with your initial time limit and check the [solution status](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplex.html?view=kc#getStatus()) when it finishes.  Then, if necessary, change parameters and call `solve()` again for phase 2 (i.e., CPLEX will continue with the partially explored MIP tree).